# How to get an array of numbers from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

How would you get an array of numbers from a javascript string?
Say I have the following:

```
var slop = "I bought 3 but 8 4.2 of them, mmmmhghrhghrghghrgh456";
```

How could you get the following array:

```
nums = [3, 8, 4.2, 456];
```

Note: I'd like to not have to use jQuery if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this :

```
var s = "I bought 3 but 8 4.2 of them, mmmmhghrhghrghghrgh456";
var nums = s.split(/[^\d\.]+/).map(parseFloat)
    .filter(function(v){ return v===v });
```

Result : `[3, 8, 4.2, 456]`

Answer (score 1):

Basic regex fetching:

```
var string = 'I bought 3 but 8 4.2 of them, mmmmhghrhghrghghrgh456 hello.45';
var result = string.match(/((?:\d+\.?\d*)|(?:\.\d+))/g);
console.log(result);
```

Result:

```
["3", "8", "4.2", "456", ".45"]
```

**Edit**

Updated to work with non-prefixed 0.xx decimals. If that's not what you want, this was the old regex to match it as (ignore dot) full numeral:

```
var result = string.match(/(\d+\.?\d*)/g);
```

Old Result:

```
["3", "8", "4.2", "456", "45"]
```